# How to change an order of mount points if a volume is mounted twice?

Tags: mount, mountpoint

**How to change an order of mount points if a volume is mounted twice (or more)?**

sudo mount /dev/sda2 /media/Folder_1;

sudo mount /dev/sda2 /media/Folder_2;

udisksctl info --block-device /dev/sda2;

...
org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Filesystem:

```
MountPoints:        /media/Folder_2 

                    /media/Folder_1
```

...

**How to change this order? I mean I want to see: *first* - "/media/Folder_1", *then* - "/media/Folder_2"
Where this order is stored?**

[Alternate:]

**Does exist a call to some system program that software (like file managers) uses to detect which mountpoint should be used?**

Eg.: a_program an_argument_1 ...  an_argument_N

(In this case it may be possible to override such program and preprocess its arguments before actual call)

---

P.S. It may be important, as I suspect that some software (like file managers) get the FIRST mount point and associates this one with the volume label.

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be to mount Folder_1 on Folder_2, instead of mounting the device on Folder_2, using bind mounts:

```
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /media/Folder_1
sudo mount -o bind /media/Folder_1 /media/Folder_2
```

This way, the device is never mounted on the second folder, but all its files are visible there.

Comment: No, it is not a solution (order will not be changed)!!! I.e., file managers (after start a new program instance) still associate "/media/Folder_2" (not "/media/Folder_1") with volume label of /dev/sda2.

Comment: @ChapaikinVA Did you unmount your previous mounts? As far as I know, no file manager do this association with bind mounts.

Comment: I have unmounted first. Effect is the same: the order is the same (i.e., the problem remains). File manager (aftrer reopened) does such association, i.e., associates volume label and mount point: volume label is used as displayname of a drive (in device list panel), and mount point is displayed in location bar. And not only file managers. All system dialogs (file open / save etc.) also uses such association. (I use KUbuntu, i.e., KDE)

Answer (score 0):

You can give a pass number in /etc/fstab. The higher the number the later it'll mount.

Comment: Do a pass number affects a mount order, but not a checks order?

Comment: Don't know. I guess mounts and checks take place at the same time, because it's not until mount starts that are checks required can be answered.

Comment: I think it will not help. As actually (via fstab) I normally mount a volume, and then mount its subfolder as binded. So bind-mount goes chronologically AFTER the mount of the entire volume. But after I log in I see that the order is always alphabetically, by descending (i.e., the problem remains). [But I will try to change the pass number.]